# AWS elasticbeanstalk Docker image delete error returns

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This is what I have.
I think some images depend on others.
I read it on AWS Elasticbeanstalk but cannot find any solution..
what's the problem it is??

```html
2022/08/29 08:15:39.328090 [INFO] Executing instruction: Clean up Docker
2022/08/29 08:15:39.328110 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker ps -aq
2022/08/29 08:15:39.446093 [INFO] 7e5f13b1cfd0
88bdc7e55084
dfea81344841

2022/08/29 08:15:39.446123 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker images | sed 1d
2022/08/29 08:15:39.568629 [INFO] current_backend    latest      9ad367c406db   29 seconds ago   125MB
current_nginx      latest      98764f877a40   36 seconds ago   142MB
current_frontend   latest      7cfffba8a632   37 seconds ago   498MB
nginx              latest      2b7d6430f78d   6 days ago       142MB
node               16-alpine   5dcd1f6157bd   12 days ago      115MB

2022/08/29 08:15:39.568666 [INFO] save docker tag command: docker tag 9ad367c406db current_backend:latest
2022/08/29 08:15:39.568672 [INFO] save docker tag command: docker tag 98764f877a40 current_nginx:latest
2022/08/29 08:15:39.568676 [INFO] save docker tag command: docker tag 7cfffba8a632 current_frontend:latest
2022/08/29 08:15:39.568681 [INFO] save docker tag command: docker tag 2b7d6430f78d nginx:latest
2022/08/29 08:15:39.568686 [INFO] save docker tag command: docker tag 5dcd1f6157bd node:16-alpine
2022/08/29 08:15:39.568698 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker rm `docker ps -aq`
2022/08/29 08:15:39.727995 [INFO] Error response from daemon: You cannot remove a running container 7e5f13b1cfd0504c1d88ce5411fcfd472dd7a46d3358cc31a661a117601b097a. Stop the container before attempting removal or force remove
Error response from daemon: You cannot remove a restarting container 88bdc7e550848d301587f5b23bce28d4bc2ad31d8cb83338446f3cc0c13daffd. Stop the container before attempting removal or force remove
Error response from daemon: You cannot remove a running container dfea813448417f77bc0c2f3aafba9ecd681c781a5b3d464f32e881f619401eac. Stop the container before attempting removal or force remove

2022/08/29 08:15:39.728023 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker rmi `docker images -aq`
2022/08/29 08:15:39.914127 [INFO] Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 75ad0b0f2a64 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 9ad367c406db (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 7e5f13b1cfd0
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 27dcdc42ac04 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 4a8cdbd7fa38 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 98764f877a40 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 88bdc7e55084
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 7cfffba8a632 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container dfea81344841
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete d0a852132853 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete f309019c890d (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 9d7c441ba690 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 26ad00a90778 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 2b7d6430f78d (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 5dcd1f6157bd (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
```